# Why sequential if statements only works if the last condition is met?

Tags: python, numbers

For an exercise, I have to append a string depending on if the input number has certain integers as a factor. The following code only seems to work when my input has 7 as a factor, so ok for 7 (expected = "Plong"), 21 (expected = "PlingPlong"). Also does not work for 35 (expected = "PangPlong").

```
def convert(number):
    sound = ""
    if number % 3 == 0:
        sound = "Pling"
    if number % 5 == 0:
        sound = "Plang"
    if number % 7 == 0:
        sound = "Plong"
    else:
        sound = str(number)
    return sound


print(convert(6))
```

Comment: did you maybe mean `sound += ...`?

Comment: I did mean that. Thanks.. but still the second problem with else as noted by @Mureinik below was causing incorrect answers.

Comment: @H2H2 You are a beginner, right? :) We make some serious mistakes when we are new to something. [String manipulation in Python](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/string-manipulation-in-python) and [Python if else](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-if-else/), you should check them out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems here.

First, in every `if`, you're overwriting the `sound` instead of appending to it, so you're mishandling numbers with multiple relevant factors.
Second, the `else` only relates to the last `if`, so if the number isn't divisible by `7`, you'll overwrite the `sound` with the string representation of `number`. One way to solve this is to hold a boolean of whether the number has a "special" sound or not, and update it in the `if` statements:

```py
def convert(number):
    special = False
    sound = ""
    if number % 3 == 0:
        sound += "Pling"
        special = True
    if number % 5 == 0:
        sound += "Plang"
        special = True
    if number % 7 == 0:
        sound += "Plong"
        special = True
    if not special:
        sound = str(number)
    return sound
```

**EDIT:**
As Hampus Larson pointed out in the comments, the `special` variable can be omited, and the `sound` can be checked directly:

```py
def convert(number):
    sound = ""
    if number % 3 == 0:
        sound += "Pling"
    if number % 5 == 0:
        sound += "Plang"
    if number % 7 == 0:
        sound += "Plong"
    if not sound:
        sound = str(number)
    return sound
```

Comment: Isn't the `special` variable redundant? The Truthyness of an empty string is `False` so you should be able to just do `if not sound: return str(number)`.

Comment: @HampusLarsson neat simplification, good point. I've edited in to my answer (with the relevant credit statement, of course)

Answer (score 0):

That is certainly not the way of appending strings **@H2H2**. You want to append to the variable sound if the input number has certain integers as a factor. This is how you can do that,

**EDIT:**
As user Hampus Larson pointed out, the `sound` can be checked directly. Thanks to him!. This way we increase the performance of the code.

```
def convert(number):
  sound = ''
  
  if number % 3 == 0:
    sound += "Pling"
  
  if number % 5 == 0:
    sound += "Plang"

  if number % 7 == 0:
    sound += "Plong"

  if not sound:
    return str(number)

  return sound
```

You append strings in Python something like this, you use the `+` operator as you use it to add two numbers,

```
str1 = "H2H2"
str2 = "2H2H"

print(str1 + str2)
# H2H22H2H

str1 += str2

print(str1)
# H2H22H2H
```

And the way you thought you were solving the problem is wrong because the `else` clause only belongs to the last `if` clause and will only get executed if the `if`
fails at some point.

And to answer your question **Why sequential if statements only works if the last condition is met** I can only say that you were doing mistakes in appending the string instead of appending them you were re-assigning the variable `sound` that is what makes the unexpected behaviour of your program.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
def convert(number):
    sound = ""
    if number % 3 == 0:
        sound += "Pling"
    if number % 5 == 0:
        sound += "Plang"
    if number % 7 == 0:
        sound += "Plong"
    if sound == '':
        sound = str(number)
    return sound


print(convert(35))    #PlangPlong
```

Comment: `convert(3)` returns `'3'` because your `else` statement is hit if the given number is not divisible by `7`.

Comment: This does not work as expected, because of the else issue noted by @Mureinik above. e.g. print(convert(3)), will output 3, but expected is "Pling"

Comment: sorry, i forget to add some code.Thanks@HampusLarsson for awareness